# Agregar punto a cadena (python)

Tags: python, lista

necesito agregar un punto a una cadena contenida en una lista, por ejemplo la palabra superman que esta en la lista [0][0] quiero que quede como su.perman, probe con replace e insert pero no me funciono, no se que estoy haciendo mal :c, de antemano muchas gracias.

dejo la lista con la que estoy probando esto por si ayuda

```
aMovi = [#    @           %           &
     ['Superman' , '12500' , '21-03-2019'],
     ['Batman'   , '10000' , '20-04-2019'],
     ['Ironman'  , '25000' , '19-01-2018'],
     ['Thor'     , '08000' , '10-10-2019'],
     ['Rambo'    , '12000' , '01-01-2017'],
     ['Hulk'     , '07500' , '07-05-2020'],
     ['Dn Ramon' , '12000' , '01-01-2010'],
     ['El Chavo' , '07500' , '07-05-2020']
    ]
```

Comment: ¿Algo así: `aMovi[0][0][:2] + '.' + aMovi[0][0][2:]`?

Comment: nose como dar poner que me sirvo asi que respondo por aqui, me sirvió mucho,muchas gracias se agradece su ayuda <333

Answer (score 0):

#### Yo lo hice así, espero te sirva

```
aMovi = [#    @           %           &
        ['Superman' , '12500' , '21-03-2019'],
        ['Batman'   , '10000' , '20-04-2019'],
        ['Ironman'  , '25000' , '19-01-2018'],
        ['Thor'     , '08000' , '10-10-2019'],
        ['Rambo'    , '12000' , '01-01-2017'],
        ['Hulk'     , '07500' , '07-05-2020'],
        ['Dn Ramon' , '12000' , '01-01-2010'],
        ['El Chavo' , '07500' , '07-05-2020']]

list_aux =list(aMovi[0][0])
#list_aux ==> ['S','u','p','e','r','m','a','n']
list_aux.insert(2,'.')
#list_aux ==> ['S','u','.','p','e','r','m','a','n']
palabra=''.join(list_aux)
#palabra ==> 'Su.perman'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta corta:**

No queda muy claro si sólo quieres modificar `Superman` o toda la primera columna. En el caso de que quieras modificar todos los valores, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```py
for m in aMovi:
    m[0] = m[0][:2] + '.' + m[0][2:]
```

**Respuesta larga:**

Las cadenas o *string* son inmutables por lo que no se puede hacer como si fuera una lista. Es decir, el siguiente código dará un error:

```py
x = "superman"
x[2:2] = '.'
print(x)
# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Una forma podría ser convirtiendo la cadena a una lista de caracteres, añadir el `.` y convertirla otra vez a cadena.

```py
x = "superman"
x = list(x)
x[2:2] = '.'
print("".join(x))
# Salida
# su.perman
```

O también puedes crear una nueva cadena tomando los fragmentos y añadiendo el `.`

```py
x = "superman"
x = x[:2] + '.' + x[2:]
print(x)
#su.perman
```